# Passing a MongoDB connection to Servant

Tags: mongodb, haskell, servant

I'm having a little bit of trouble using Servant with the MongoDB library. I am pretty new to Haskell and Servant, so I suspect my technique is wrong.
I have two endpoints one to fetch a `[Event]` and one to create a new `Event`. So the two signatures are:

```
handleNewEvent :: Event -> Handler PostResult
handleListEvents :: Handler [Event]
```

Similar to examples in Postgres, I have added a database connection to my server. By running something like this:

```
db :: MonadIO m => Action m a -> m a
let db = access pipe master dbName

run port $ serve api $ server db
```

So now I can create a server function:

```
server :: MonadIO m => (Action m a -> m a) -> Server API                              
server runAction = handleFindEvents runAction :<|> handleNewEvent runAction
```

My problem is I need the runAction function to be `Action IO () -> IO ()` in handleNewEvent but `Action IO [Event] -> IO [Event]` in handleListEvent.
I suspect I'm approaching the problem from the wrong perspective (this would be how I would tackle the problem in another language). How is this meant to work using Servant?
For reference here are my handler functions. I hardcoded the list handler to ensure the code compiles and runs.

```
newEvent :: DBContext -> Event -> Handler PostResult           
newEvent context event = do                                    
    liftIO $ context $ insert_ "events" $ toBson event         
    return $ PostResult { message = "success" , success = True}
                                                               
findEvents :: DBContext  -> Handler [Event]                    
findEvents run = return [Event "example" "event"]
```

Comment: Does it help if you declare `server` as `server :: MonadIO m => (forall a. Action m a -> m a) -> Server API` (requires `-XRank2Types` or `-XRankNTypes`)?

Comment: @MarkSeemann that got me to a program that compiles and appears to work. I had to omit the type constraint (I think that's what it is) of MonadIO. My signature now looks like `server :: (forall a. Action IO a -> IO a) -> Server API`. Thanks!